# mysql command line sql execution mystery, only part of the string is considered

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

from command line from my Mac terminal:

`mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 -uroot -p"mypass" wordpress -e "update users set user_pass = '$1$Hat7oFty$mA.L2vsQdD3MxvxAuDFKp0';"`

completes successfully...

however.... only `.L2vsQdD3MxvxAuDFKp0` is written to the user_pass field in every row. Whiskey Tango Foxtrot?

[image]

Needless to say when I issue `update users set user_pass = '$1$Hat7oFty$mA.L2vsQdD3MxvxAuDFKp0';` directly to the DB from an application like DataGrip it takes the whole string correctly....

Comment: Is php code making the command line call?

Comment: No. Me, manually from my Mac terminal.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used bash. Could it be thinking `$1$Hat7oFty$mA` is a variable it should be substituting with?

Comment: hmmm didn't think of that. I guess I have to 'escape' it someohow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` are part of shell variables, which are unintentionally get replaced. You have to escape the `$` character to keep it in the string as a literal `$`.

```
$ echo "$1$Hat7oFty$mA.L2vsQdD3MxvxAuDFKp0"
.L2vsQdD3MxvxAuDFKp0
$ echo "\$1\$Hat7oFty\$mA.L2vsQdD3MxvxAuDFKp0"
$1$Hat7oFty$mA.L2vsQdD3MxvxAuDFKp0
```